# How do I export a Word document as a PNG?

Tags: microsoft-word, png

I have a Microsoft Word 2010 document which I want to save as a `.png` image file, so I can include it as part of a PowerPoint slide.

In Powerpoint, there's a built in "Save As" option for exporting slides as png image files. However, no such option seems to exist in Microsoft Word.

**How can I export a Word 2010 document as a .png image file?**

Comment: Online converter: [DOCX to PNG](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/docx-to-png)

Comment: Another one: [Convert DOC (WORD) to PNG. Online & Free](https://convertio.co/doc-png/)

Comment: You may convert it online in [Online Convert](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png) or in [Office Converter](http://office-converter.com/Convert-to-PNG). Did you try LibreOffice or OpenOffice word software?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install PDFCreator (Free software)
2. Open World file
3. Ctrl + P
4. Select PDFCreator as a Printer
5. Print
6. PDFCreator Dailog open
7. Click on the icon beside file for output types(**PDF, JPG, PNG etc**)
8. Select PNG
9. Save

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no native method of exporting a Word document as an image format because the whole point of Word is for word processing.

You will need to export the document to PDF (Save As...) and then use a third party application to export the PDF page(s) to your desired format; and then insert them into the application/document you intend the final result.

Comment: For example you can use GIMP to open PDF page and then save it as PNG.

Comment: Even Adobe Reader can export to JPG, but, yes, many programs can export PDF to other formats.

Comment: Adobe Reader can't (full Adobe Acrobat is required according to https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-do-I-convert-an-adobe-file-to-jpeg-q147752.aspx ).

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting there to be a tool that somehow can save a 50 page Word doc into some image of arbitrary dimensions, then you are out of luck.

However, if you are using Windows and want just a page or screenful of the Word doc, just open the doc and take the built-in Snipping Tool (in All Programs--> Accessories).  You can zoom in or out with Word to get more onscreen if needed.

Clip a rectangle around the page or whatever you want in the ppt and save the snip, the default is .png but it saves as .jpg also.